# Drag and drop with an image

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I need to create a drag and drop system in swing where an image of the thing being dragged is attached to the cursor during the drag. In theory this is achieveable with

```
public Icon TransferHandler.getVisualRepresentation(Transferable t)
```

but there appears to be a long standing bug ([here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4816922)) that means this method is never called. I know I can do it by implementing my own DnD system with DragSource etc., but does anyone know of an easier workround that will get me what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I used the old style drag-and-drop to implement what I wanted. However I have no reason to think abrightwell's solution wouldn't work just as well - this was just the best way at the time.

Answer (score 3):

The method `TransferHandler.getVisualRepresentation` wasn't supported in java 1.4, I'm not sure if or when it was fixed. To test whether it works in a current version you could adapt this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/TransferHandlersubclasswrapsanotherTransferHandleranddelegatesmostofitsoperationstothewrappedhandler.htm)

Comment: It wasn't fixed in the version I have, Mac version 1.6.0.

Answer (score 2):

You could Try putting the image on a Jlabel (in the draggesture recognizer)and set its bounds, in the droptargetListener dragover method.  Alternately, hows about implementing a Mouse listener (I've not tested this latter method).

Answer (score 1):

I have used the "work around" suggested towards the bottom of the bug report you have listed.  It worked well enough for me.  Granted I was using this with Mac OS X so I have no idea whether Winderz will support it.  It would be nice if they would at least fix it to work like they intended and simply document where it will and won't work... oh well.  Good Luck.