# Rendering Dragged object during drag

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable

I have been stuck on this problem for a while now. I want to drag a row in a jtable to reorder it. But I really want the user to see the row while dragging it and not just the default "drag" rectangle symbol. So I took a look at the java  [DnD tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) finding it very useful, but..

The problem is that I still dont know which method I should override to get this going.

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in this question [Drag and Drop with an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427879/drag-and-drop-with-an-image). However as far as I know this only works on Mac.